# Content region not visible in blocks setup page in Sky Adaptive Theme

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I checked the 'content' region, being one of the prerequisite regions and it is present and referenced in the sky.info file as well as in the page.tpl.php.

That is:
(in sky.info file)

```
regions[content] = Main content
```

(in page.tpl.php file)

```
        <div id="content"><?php print render($page['content']); ?></div>
```

However, when I go into the 'block' setup GUI page, from the regions dropdown, I can not see the 'content' region option.

Any idea as to why its not visible would be great. Cheers

Comment: Have you checked this after clearing cache?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Sky theme are you using? In 7.x-2.3, I can see the "Main content" region in the drop down list. If you have made custom changes to theme, try clearing the cache.

[image: sky theme]

Comment: thanks Ajinkya but I cannot see it. I have been carefully making changes to the sky theme (2.3) but this strange behaviour took me by surprise.

Hence the question to ensure 'Content' code only goes into these two files mentioned above.

Comment: @Kayote generally a .info file is enough for Drupal to recognize that your theme has blocks. You don't even need print statements for block to show in the drop down list. You can verify  this by creating a new theme with just .info file and putting region[content]=Main content (and name=MyTheme, core=7.x,engine=phptemplate etc.). Drupal will pick it up. Please check if you any syntax error or typo in .info file and browser has not cached any data for your site.

Comment: Thanks Ajinkya, did have a comb through & couldn't find anything of note. Will continue on with the search, I suspect its something quite minor.